# ons-modalにパラメータを渡したい

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs

monacaのonseneUIでモーダルを表示する時にパラメータを渡して、そのパラメータを表示するようにしたいのですが、うまくいきません。
公式リファレンスは読んだのですが、具体例がないのでよくわからないです。
パラメータの渡し方・取得方法を教えてください。

現在のコード

```html
<ons-page>

  <div ng-click="modal.show({num:1});">show</div>
  
  <ons-modal var="modal" animation="lift" direction="up">
    <div>{{modal.num}}</div>
  </ons-modal>

</ons-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ons-page**にコントローラを指定し、**ons-modal**上に表示させるためのプロパティ「**modalText**」を用意します。
モーダル表示メソッド「**showModal()**」を呼び出し、「**modalText**」を書き換えてモーダルを表示させれば実現できます。

```js
var app = ons.bootstrap("myApp", ["onsen"]);
app.controller("testController", function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.modalText = "";
  ons.ready(function () {
  });
  $scope.showModal = function (msg) {
    $scope.modalText = msg;
    $scope.myModal.show();
    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.myModal.hide();
    }, 3000);
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@latest/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@latest/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@latest/js/onsenui.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@latest/js/angular-onsenui.js"></script>
<ons-page ng-controller="testController">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">ons-modal</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item>
      <ons-button ng-click="showModal('おまちください')">おまちください</ons-button>
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item>
      <ons-button ng-click="showModal('Just a moment')">Just a moment</ons-button>
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
  <ons-modal var="myModal" animation="lift" direction="up">{{modalText}}</ons-modal>
</ons-page>
```